# Where can I find default noisy color backgrounds?

Tags: find, default, desktop-background

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version.

I want to change login screen background to as like my lock screen background. I know how to change login screen background but I can't find the default color backgrounds of ubuntu. Where can I found these pictures?

[image: Color Backgrounds]

Edit: Okay, I figured out, they are actually not backgrounds, just a samples of colours. Ubuntu adding the noise to those colors using this texture:

/usr/share/gnome-control-center/pixmaps/noise-texture-light.png

I made my own wallpaper using noise texture and applied it to login screen.